# Wrong results cufft 3D in-place

Tags: cuda, cufft

I write because I'm facing problems with the cufft 3D transform in-place, while I have no problems for the out-of-place version. I tried to follow Robert Crovella's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809179/cufft-double-to-complex) but I'm not obtaining the correct results when I make a FFT+IFT.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cufft.h>

// Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int N = 4; 
    double *in = NULL, *d_in = NULL;
    cuDoubleComplex *out = NULL, *d_out = NULL;
    cufftHandle plan_r2c, plan_c2r;

    unsigned int out_mem_size = sizeof(cuDoubleComplex) * N*N*(N/2 + 1);
    unsigned int in_mem_size = out_mem_size;

    in  = (double *) malloc (in_mem_size);
    out  = (cuDoubleComplex *)in;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_in, in_mem_size);
    d_out = (cuDoubleComplex *)d_in;

    cufftPlan3d(&plan_r2c, N, N, N, CUFFT_D2Z);
    cufftPlan3d(&plan_c2r, N, N, N, CUFFT_Z2D);

    memset(in, 0, in_mem_size);
    unsigned int idx;
    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
                idx = z + N * ( y + x * N);
                in[idx] = idx;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nStart: \n");
    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
        printf("plane = %d ----------------------------\n", z);
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++){
                idx = z + N * ( y + x * N);
                printf("%.3f \t", in[idx]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, in, in_mem_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cufftExecD2Z(plan_r2c, (cufftDoubleReal *)d_in, (cufftDoubleComplex *)d_out);
    cufftExecZ2D(plan_c2r, (cufftDoubleComplex *)d_out, (cufftDoubleReal *)d_in);

    memset(in, 0, in_mem_size);
    CU_ERR_CHECK( cudaMemcpy(in, d_in, in_mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    printf("\nAfter FFT+IFT: \n");
    for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
        printf("plane = %d ----------------------------\n", z);
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++){
                idx = z + N * ( y + x * N);
                // Normalisation
                in[idx] /= (N*N*N);
                printf("%.3f \t", in[idx]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs the following data:

Starting file

plane = 0 ----------------------------

0.000   4.000   8.000   12.000
16.000  20.000  24.000  28.000
32.000  36.000  40.000  44.000
48.000  52.000  56.000  60.000

plane = 1 ----------------------------

1.000   5.000   9.000   13.000
17.000  21.000  25.000  29.000
33.000  37.000  41.000  45.000
49.000  53.000  57.000  61.000

plane = 2 ----------------------------

2.000   6.000   10.000  14.000
18.000  22.000  26.000  30.000
34.000  38.000  42.000  46.000
50.000  54.000  58.000  62.000

plane = 3 ----------------------------

3.000   7.000   11.000  15.000
19.000  23.000  27.000  31.000
35.000  39.000  43.000  47.000
51.000  55.000  59.000  63.000

After FFT+IFT

plane = 0 ----------------------------

-0.000  -0.344  8.000   12.000
-0.031  20.000  24.000  -0.031
32.000  36.000  0.031   44.000
48.000  -0.094  56.000  60.000

plane = 1 ----------------------------

1.000   -0.000  9.000   13.000
-0.000  21.000  25.000  0.125
33.000  37.000  0.000   45.000
49.000  0.000   57.000  61.000

plane = 2 ----------------------------

2.000   6.000   -0.000  14.000
18.000  0.000   26.000  30.000
0.000   38.000  42.000  -0.000
50.000  54.000  -0.000  62.000

plane = 3 ----------------------------

3.000   7.000   0.031   15.000
19.000  -0.031  27.000  31.000
-0.031  39.000  43.000  0.031
51.000  55.000  0.031   63.000

I even tried to pad the data this way:

```
// With padding
    unsigned int idx;
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++){
            for (int z = 0; z < 2*(N/2+1); z++){
                idx = z + N * ( y + x * N);
                if (z < 4) in[idx] = idx;
                else in[idx] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already found out, you need padding if you use the `CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_FFTW_PADDING`compatibility mode which is default. For your code to work you could use [cufftSetCompatibilityMode()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftsetcompatibilitymode) to set `CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE`. However, this mode is marked as deprecated in the current version of CUDA.

Therefore, I recommend to use the default compatibility mode and use padding. Your try to implement padding is wrong. The formula to calculate a linear index for 3 dimension x, y, z where z is the fastest running index is `idx = z + Nz*(y + Ny*x)`. The size `Nz` of the `z` dimension including padding is `Nz = (N/2+1)*2`. Then, the correct initialization of the array is:

```
unsigned int idx;
for (int z = 0; z < N; z++){
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++){
            idx = z + (N/2+1)*2 * ( y + x * N);
            in[idx] = idx;
        }
    }
}
```

Accordingly for the print loops.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast, detailed and correct answer. I was pretty much settled on using the out-of-place version but this really helps me to save half of the memory.